# CycloneDX: What is the use of a component's type?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I try to configure [cyclonedx-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/CycloneDX/cyclonedx-gradle-plugin) and struggle with `projectType`: I can see in the source that this is passed as parameter `type` to `org.cyclonedx.model.Component`, where it's resolved to [an enum of the same name](https://github.com/CycloneDX/cyclonedx-core-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/cyclonedx/model/Component.java#L66). But I cannot see what it's used for.

I tried [the docs](https://cyclonedx.org/docs/1.4/json/#components_items_type), but they do not only not say what the type is for, they are even kind of contradictory:

- The paragraph above the bullet points reads "For software components, **classify as application** if no more specific appropriate classification is available or cannot be determined for the component"
- But the bullet point `library` reads "If not, or is unknown, then specifying library is RECOMMENDED". `library` is the default, btw.

So: Why would I care? What is the `projectType`/`type` used for and what's a good default?

PS: The last question is of importance, as one can use `cyclonedx-gradle-plugin` with a `gradle.init` file for *multiple* projects, which can be of multiple types, I guess...

Comment: please ask your question here: https://github.com/CycloneDX/specification/issues

Comment: @jko I rather don't. The form says "Be sure to review the contributing guidelines", which state "Have a question? Rather than opening an issue, ask away on Stack Overflow."